# How do I draw the BTS and the user on the polygon and also increase the number of Polygon on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment

I am trying to draw the structure of a cellular mobile network on MATLAB, I used this code:
Draw Function:

```
function []=draw(n, R, x_o, y_o, c)

if ~exist('c','var')
    c = 'k';
end

k = 0:(n-1);

x = x_o + R * sin(2*pi*k/n);
y = y_o + R * cos(2*pi*k/n);

xplot = [x, x(1)];
yplot = [y, y(1)];

plot(xplot, yplot, 'color', c)
```

Main code:

```
R = 0.2 ;
n = 6;
x_o = 1; y_o = 1;

draw(n, R, x_o, y_o, 'b')
axis equal
hold on

draw(n, R, x_o - R*sqrt(3), y_o, 'c')
draw(n, R, x_o - R*sqrt(3)/2, y_o + 3*R/2, 'g')
draw(n, R, x_o - R*sqrt(3)/2, y_o - 3*R/2, 'k')

draw(n, R, x_o + R*sqrt(3), y_o, 'm')
draw(n, R, x_o + R*sqrt(3)/2, y_o + 3*R/2, 'r')
draw(n, R, x_o + R*sqrt(3), y_o, 'y')
draw(n, R, x_o + R*sqrt(3)/2, y_o + 3*R/2, 'b')
draw(n, R, x_o + R*sqrt(3)/2, y_o - 3*R/2,'w')
draw(n, R, x_o + R*sqrt(3)/2, y_o - 3*R/2, [1 .5 0])

hold off
```

This only draws a 7 hexagon block, I need something like 12 or 25 hexagon blocks with users and also BTS at the centre of each block and the users around the BTS